# Default space between UIBarButtonItems on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a `UINavigationBar` on which I have put `UIBarButtonItems`. iPhone by default puts a space of 10 between the button items. I want to know what variable denotes this space? To be more clear - I would like to know the variable that can get me the space between the `UIBarButtonItems` on my `UINavigationBar`.

Thanks

Comment: That was stated in private API. You can ask apple directly

Answer (score 3):

The published approach for doing this on a toolBar or navBar in any version of the SDK below iOS 6 is via something like this.

```
b = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
```

You use the UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace style property to add a dummy button. You don't have control over specific dimensions and the system will space it out for you. Works perfectly fine in most cases.

Or if you need more precise control you have to create a custom button.

So, you can use one of the above approaches NOW, and I DO suggest you try out the FlexibleSpace option if your not familiar with it.

Or you can wait for iOS 6, that version of the SDK has some other ways to do what you want, but we are under NDA until that is released. You can either log into the iPhone Developer portal and look up the documents yourself or wait until iOS 6 is released.

Comment: Thx. :) The other options are also completely valid for right now. It CAN be done with custom view managing the leading and trailing space.

Comment: I need an exact space of 8 between two buttons. Hence using FlexibleSpace style doesn't work out. However, as per another question (unable to get its link back will update when I get it), the solution suggests giving a -10 space to get exact spacing. However this solution has an issue that if in any version they change 10 space to 20, the 8 space difference will 18. Is there any way to that in 5.1.1 SDK without having to hard code the value of 10.

Comment: There is a way to do it. Create your own Custom Button. Have the visible image of the button exactly the number of pixels you need away from the edge of some background or container view that is clear.

Comment: Tried doing that. But if I keep it say 8 spaces away from the border of its container, and say I don't add a -10 space, the result is it goes 18 spaces from its left button. I need a way to query to UI, how much space it is adding between the buttons so that I can fix the space between them independent of the changes caused by SDKs

Comment: Another option is to create your own button bar control and manage the position of custom views in there. Give it a clear background and float it over a portion of the other button bar.